# ASP.net Core C# Linq Distinct not working

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor

I've trying to use Linq for the first time to get distinct values from a list in ASP.net Core Razor Pages.

For this i'm using the below code but it just returns all the rows from the original list including the duplicates:

```
PLDistinct = PL.Select(p => new ProcessListSummary {  Title=  p.Title, 
                                                  WSID = p.WSID,
                                                  QImageTnURL = p.QImageTnURL,
                                                  QImageURL = p.QImageURL,
                                                  QDescription = p.QDescription,
                                                  PComplete= p.PComplete,
                                                  MIdent = p.MIdent,
                                                  WID = p.WID})
                                                  .Distinct().ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Many thanks

Comment: Your class `ProcessListSummary ` probably doesn't override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, Linq uses this to determine whether one object is equal to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `ProcessListSummary` probably does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, so the default will be used from [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.referenceequals?view=net-5.0) that just compares references. You use always a new instance of `ProcessListSummary`, so all are considered to be unequal.

So either override `Equals`+`GetHashCode` meaningfully, by comparing the relevant properties, and/or implement `IEquatable<ProcessListSummary>`(in the same way) or pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<ProcessListSummary>` to `Distinct`. The latter should be done if you have multiple ways to compare this class or you don't want to change (or can't change) it in general.

Another option is to use `Distinct` on an anonymous type or tuple which provide that feature:

```
PLDistinct = PL
    .Select(p => (p.Title,p.WSID,p.QImageTnURL,p.QImageURL,p.QDescription,p.PComplete,p.MIdent,p.WID))
    .Distinct()
    .Select(p => new ProcessListSummary {  Title=  p.Title, 
                                           WSID = p.WSID,
                                           QImageTnURL = p.QImageTnURL,
                                           QImageURL = p.QImageURL,
                                           QDescription = p.QDescription,
                                           PComplete= p.PComplete,
                                           MIdent = p.MIdent,
                                           WID = p.WID})
    .ToList();
```